# How to get the records from the current month in App Engine (Python) Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore

Given the following entity:

```
class DateTest(db.Model):
    dateAdded = db.DateTimeProperty()
    #...
```

What would be the best way to get the records from the current month?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. For example, using `Query`:

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db

q = db.Query(DateTest)

# This month
month = datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

q.filter('dateAdded >= ', month)
results = q.fetch(10)
```

Comment: thanks Dan.  I think the correct assignment for month should be: month = datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

Comment: I added a 'from datetime import datetime' statement at the top of the example instead of just 'import datetime', because I find I usually use datetime more than once when I've imported it. Your example works too. :)

Comment: @Dan: That explicitly goes against the Google style guide.

Comment: @Guido: Yeah, bad habit. Fixed it above.

Comment: @DanHolevoet can you please help me solve this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505732/datastore-filter-by-date-interal

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

DateTest.gql("WHERE dateAdded.month:1", now.month)
```

Comment: GQL has no feature to select the month of a datetime value for use as the left-hand side of a query filter.